# ListView Highlight selected items

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I can't highlight all the selected items. Only one item is highlighted at a time. If next item is clicked the previous highlighted item goes back to normal.

Here is my CustomAdapter

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>> {

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> Strings) {

            //let android do the initializing :)
            super(context, textViewResourceId, Strings);
        }

        public void setSelectedIndex(int ind)
        {
            selectedIndex = ind;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return dataList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, Object> getItem(int position)
        {
            return dataList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        //class for caching the views in a row
        private class ViewHolder {

            TextView not, isRead;
            LinearLayout noti_linear;
        }

        //Initialise
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {

                //inflate the custom layout
                convertView = inflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notification_layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                //cache the views
                viewHolder.noti_linear = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.not_layout);
                viewHolder.not = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_noti);
                viewHolder.isRead = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_isRead);

                //link the cached views to the convertview
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            //set the data to be displayed
            viewHolder.not.setText(dataList.get(position).get("CheckList").toString());

            if(selectedIndex!= -1 && position == selectedIndex)
            {
                viewHolder.noti_linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder.noti_linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }


//            if (getItemId(position) == StringHolder.mSelectedItem) {
//                viewHolder.noti_linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
//
//            } else {
//                viewHolder.noti_linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
//            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Here is my onItemClick

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                cardAdapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
            }
        });
```

Comment: you could try to make an array that holds all the items that were selected and then use them like that

Comment: Try with multi-selected list http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-delete-multiple-selected-items-listview-tutorial/ and https://techienotes.info/2015/09/13/how-to-select-multiple-items-in-android-listview/

Comment: @MNM can you show how ? Or any links ? Thanks

Comment: @SathishKumarJ I don't want to select actualy. I need to change the background just to show that its read or unread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by below code instead of applying in adapter class,
Check below code,

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            //cardAdapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Enjoy your coding, you can also achieve it by your way but for that you need to declare List<Integer> selectedIndex instead of int and then also need to declare same in activity and pass it and then use for loop and all so instead of that this is better way

Comment: Is there any way to store this selection. If i load the list again i lose those highlighted positions.

Comment: Yes as I told you the way you have to follow those steps for that

Answer (score 0):

```
OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            mSelectedItem = position;
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

    if (position == mSelectedItem) {
        // set your color
    }

    return view;
}
```